# Issues with imbalanced dataset in case of binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, imbalanced-data

I have a binary classification problem where the data division is like :{0:85%,1:15%}. I have tried re-weighting class_weights and other sampling approches. But all the approaches that I have used is giving me unsatisfactory results.
My dataset is (91125,57).

```
Accuracy:1
F1-Score:1
F2-Score:1
Precision:1
Recall:1
AUCROC:1
Kappa:1
```

Is there any other method I can use to handle such a situation?

Comment: 85% / 15% is a pretty reasonably balanced dataset, so it's unlikely that any issues you're facing are due to class imbalance. If those figures you're sharing are metrics from your model, it's likely that you have target leak in your input features.

Comment: Can you please specify what do actually mean by target leak?

Comment: It's when your input features have information about the target that wouldn't be available when you'd score your model: https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/data-leakage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're dropping the target variable from your features before feeding the data to the classifier:

`X = df.drop('target',axis=1)
 y = df['target']`

I'd also check if some independent variables are highly correlated with the target. It may give your an idea what causes an unrealistically perfect classiification:

`import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(X_train.corr())`